# IPFS links unreliable net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200

Tags: ipfs

For an app that I build, I need to fetch metadata on IPFS. At first, it load correctly and after some time, it gives me that error :
`net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200`

No matter which IPFS gateway or which file I use, it eventually stops working. But when I access the link directly, it works fine.

Any idea what could be the cause ? Is there a more reliable way to query data on IPFS ?